# MySQL Query over multiple tables in the given example

Tags: mysql, database

I'd like to receive a table from my database but I am unable to form the query.

This is what I like to achieve: Think of a group of users who shall be invited to an event.
To find a date A list of dates are provided by the host.

So far we have these tables:

Users:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | Sally |
| 2 | Bob |
| 3 | John |
| 4 | Lisa |
| 5 | Joe |
| 6 | Jane |

Events

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Birthdayparty |
| 2 | Barbecue |
| 3 | Dinner |

Event Users:

| Id | UserId | EventId |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 1 | (Sally is invited to bp) |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | (Bob, too) |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | (and Lisa) |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | (Sally is invited. to Bbe) |
| 5 | 5 | 2 | (also Joe) |
| 6 | 4 | 2 | (and Lisa) |

So far for the structure of main parts of the db.

Now lets put some possible dates for the birthday party

EventProposal:

| Id | Event | Date |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5. March | Birthday dates |
| 2 | 1 | 6. March |  |
| 3 | 1 | 8. March |  |
| 4 | 1 | 10. March |  |
| 5 | 3 | 4. April | Dinner |
| 6 | 3 | 5. April |  |

Now the last table holds which user selected which dates for an event.

EventProposalSelection:

| Id | EventId | UserId | DateId |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | Sally selected 5. March for birthday |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | Sally selected 6. March for birthday |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | Sally selected 8. March for birthday |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 2 | Bob selected 6. March for birthday |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | Bob selected 8. March for birthday |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | 1 | 4 | 1 | Lisa selected 5. March for birthday |
| 7 | 1 | 4 | 2 | Lisa selected 6. March for birthday |
| 8 | 1 | 4 | 4 | Lisa selected 10. March for birthday |

What I like to know is if a user has picked a date for an event.
I want to see all dates of a specific event for a specific user

(where clause contains userId and eventId)

If I ask for Sally in combination of Birthday
(where userId = 1 and eventId = 1)

I'd like to receive

| DateId | Checked |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | true |
| 2 | true |
| 3 | false |
| 4 | true |

The tables are properly constrained and related to each other

How can I achieve this in MySQL?

EDIT:

```
select
e.Name EventName,
e.id,
dp.DateProposal DateOfEvent,
coalesce( u.Name, '' ) GuestName,
-- due to left-join, see if the date is chosen or NULL (not chosen)
case when dps.dateid IS NULL then false else true end DateWasPicked
from
    -- start with events
    Event e
    
     -- Now, what dates were birthday parties POSSIBLE to attend
        JOIN EventProposal dp
            on e.id = dp.EventId      
   
            -- NOW, what dates by given users were selected
            -- BUT, since not all dates may be selected, do a LEFT JOIN
            LEFT JOIN EventProposalSelection dps
                on dp.id = dps.dateid
                -- and finally who selected the given date
                -- and again LEFT-JOIN since a user may not pick all dates
                LEFT JOIN User u
                    on dps.userid = u.id
                    -- prevent getting ALL users for an event
                    AND u.Id = 7    --Sally
    where
        -- but only birthday parties
        e.Id = 1 
        -- Tricky here because you want ALL POSSIBLE event dates,
        -- but ONLY those for Sally
    AND ( dps.dateid IS NULL  OR  u.Id = 7 )
order by
    -- and suggest you actually use datetime based column
    -- as you can use functions to get the format of the date.
    dp.DateProposal
```

Lead to
[image: Request for Sally (UserId is 7]

which seems to be fine, but when running for Bob (UserId = 2)

[image]

there is a date missing

And running for John (UserId = 3)

[image: who is not invited, I still get an output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so lets take this one step at a time.  You are interested in a SPECIFIC event, and all POSSIBLE dates FOR said event.  Then, based on a specific user, if they had (or not) picked any of the possible dates.  And by the user ID, get the name too.

Sample data.  Your version of data had the sample selections with Sally's ID of 1, not 7.  So this is a sample set I ran with using 7 as the basis for Sally

```
create table users ( id integer, name varchar(10))
insert into users ( id, name ) values 
    ( 7, 'Sally' ),
    ( 2, 'Bob' ),
    ( 3, 'John' ),
    ( 4, 'Lisa' ),
    ( 5, 'Joe' ),
    ( 6, 'Jane' )

create table Events  ( id int, name varchar(15))

insert into Events (id, name ) values
    ( 1, 'Birthdayparty' ),
    ( 2, 'BBQ' ),
    ( 3, 'Dinner' )


create table EventUsers ( id int, userid int, eventid int )

insert into EventUsers ( id, userid, eventid ) values
    ( 1, 7, 1 ),
    ( 2, 2, 1 ),
    ( 3, 4, 1 ),
    ( 4, 1, 2 ),
    ( 5, 5, 2 ),
    ( 6, 4, 2 )


create table EventProposal (id int, event int, date datetime )

insert into EventProposal ( id, event, date ) values
    ( 1, 1, '2022-03-05' ),
    ( 2, 1, '2022-03-06' ),
    ( 3, 1, '2022-03-08' ),
    ( 4, 1, '2022-03-10' ),
    ( 5, 3, '2022-04-04' ),
    ( 6, 3, '2022-04-05' )


create table EventProposalSelection ( id int, eventid int, userid int, DateID int )

insert into EventProposalSelection ( id, eventid, userid, dateid ) values
    ( 1, 1, 7, 1 ),
    ( 2, 1, 7, 2 ),
    ( 3, 1, 7, 3 ),
    ( 4, 1, 2, 2 ),
    ( 5, 1, 2, 3 ),
    ( 6, 1, 4, 1 ),
    ( 7, 1, 4, 2 ),
    ( 8, 1, 4, 4 )


select
        AllEventDates.id,
        AllEventDates.EventName,
        AllEventDates.DateOfEvent,
        u.id UserID,
        coalesce( u.Name, '' ) GuestName,
        -- due to left-join, see if the date is chosen or NULL (not chosen)
        case when eps.dateid IS NULL 
            then 'false' else 'true' end DateWasPicked
    from
        Users u
        -- this query get all events and all possible dates regardless
        -- of who may have supplied a selection to attend
        JOIN 
            ( select
                    e.id,
                    e.Name EventName,
                    ep.id EventProposalID,
                    ep.date DateOfEvent
                from
                    Events e
                        JOIN EventProposal ep
                            on e.id = ep.Event 
                where
                    -- but only birthday parties
                    e.Name = 'Birthdayparty' ) AllEventDates
            on 1=1
            -- NOW, left join for a given one person
            LEFT JOIN EventProposalSelection eps
                on eps.userid = u.id
                AND AllEventDates.EventProposalID = eps.dateid
                -- and finally who selected the given date
                -- and again LEFT-JOIN since a user may not pick all dates
    where
        u.id = 7
    order by
        -- and suggest you actually use datetime based column
        -- as you can use functions to get the format of the date.
        AllEventDates.DateOfEvent
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I adapted your code my database. See edit for result. Did I transfered your code correctly?

Comment: @Jazz, see revised answer and query.  I am starting with the USER table to pre-qualify just the person in question.  The second part of the join is just to get all the dates for a given event.  The third part is for those proposals by the users matching on the userid basis.

Comment: thank you buddy for time and support! It works !